# Convert ng-click to Blaze in meteoric

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, meteor-blaze, meteoric

I used ng-click as below in ionic:

```
<div class="list">
  <a class="item item-icon-right nav-clear" href="#/app/list1" ng-click="closeMenu()">
    <i class="icon ion-ios7-paper"></i>
      Item 1
  </a>  ....
</div>
```

know I want to use [Meteor](http://meteor.com/) with [Meteoric](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic). I don't know how to convert ng-click to Blaze version. Please guide me.
I didn't find anything about this in [Meteoric guide page](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic/blob/master/GUIDE.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set up a template around your html:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <div class="list">
    <a id="myDiv" class="item item-icon-right nav-clear" href="#/app/list1">
      <i class="icon ion-ios7-paper"></i>
        Item 1
    </a>  ....
  </div>
</template>
```

Then put this code into your js file:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  "click #myDiv": function( event) {
      // yourFunction 
  },
});
```